# Binding PropertyChanged to parent property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How can I get `SelectionText` to update when a checkbox is changed.
When I raise a `PropertyChangedEvent`, `PropertyChanged` is null with a `Checked` event.

BitmaskStackPanel is the parent and displays all the checkboxes.

It's probably very simple but I havn't done this before.

```
class BitmaskStackPanel {
    public BitmaskStackPanel(string name, List<BitmaskCheckBox> checkboxes, long defaultValue = 0)
            {
                Name = name;
                _checkboxes = checkboxes;
                DefaultValue = defaultValue;

                foreach (var bmcb in Checkboxes)
                {
                    Children.Add(bmcb);
                }
            }

    public List<BitmaskCheckBox> Checkboxes
            {
                get
                {
                    return _checkboxes;
                }
            }

    public string SelectionText
            {
                get
                {
                    return ToString();
                }
            }
    }
}
    public class BitmaskCheckBox : CheckBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public BitmaskCheckBox(long value, string details, bool isChecked = false, Visibility visibility = Visibility.Visible)
        {
            Tag = value;
            Content = details;
            IsChecked = isChecked;
            Visibility = visibility;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Is that your entire BitmaskCheckBox? You have to implement proper event raising for PropertyChanged which is done when a new value is set to the ViewModel property that is bound to the view. It is best if you check out tutorials about [DataBinding](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using multiple `CheckBoxes`, so you have to use `MultiBinding` instead of simple `Binding`.

In `MultiBinding` you bind against multiple sources and write a `MultiValueConverter` to combine all coming values into single value.

Now as you are using your own property called `SelectionText`, you have to make it a Dep.Property. And apply `Binding` using Code carefully.

> You can use Binding only with DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject.

[Good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)